# Base-align text in a rotated div

Tags: css

Here is a basic sketch of what I want to achieve, but without inserting any kind of HTML entitites (Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nt1pPUujTSLEXIAagS7d?p=preview):

```css
.container {
  padding: 40px;
}
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.skew-text {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Original -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="skew-text">
      <span>
              I'm a little teapot, short and stout
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Aligned -->
  <div class="container underlined">
    <div class="skew-text">
      <span class="text">
              I'm a little &emsp;&emsp; teapot, &emsp;&emsp;short and &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;stout
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically, I would like each line of text in the rotated div to align with the red line, rather than left side of the rotated container. Is this possible only using CSS?

Comment: You could use `translateY`  to move your rotated text: http://plnkr.co/edit/f4iagfDUUBDfbjJnjAI6?p=preview - if you do it by the amount of padding (20px) then the text should touch the red line

Comment: @Pete thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem since I will still need to use entities (or something else) in order to pad each line of text in order to bring it into alignment.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood what you were after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this result with CSS shapes. You can **exclude** from the span a triangular area, that makes it flow as you want.

The problem is that this feature doesn't have much support . See the snippet in Chrome , Safari or Opera.

```css
.container {
  padding: 40px;
}
.shape {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 0);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 0%);
}
.skew-text {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="skew-text">
    <div class="shape"></div>
    <span>I'm a little teapot, short and stout</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty much perfect, a shame it does not seem to be widely supported yet. I will accept your answer in spite of this, since it is the kind of pure CSS solution I was looking for in the first place.

Comment: Happy that it helped ! And yes, it's a shame that this posibility is taking so long to be available.

Answer (score 3):

You could make the lines different elements, that would do the trick:

```css
.container {
  padding: 40px;
}
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.skew-text {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 100px;
}

.line {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container underlined">
    <div class="skew-text">
      <span class="text">
        <div class="line">I'm a little</div>
        <div class="line">teapot,</div>
        <div class="line">short and</div>
        <div class="line">stout</div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**update**

It is going to be very hard.

I've created a function that splits the text into elements if a linebreak would normally happen by checking the element's height change if we append the words one by one, but if the length of the string isn't the same as we started with, it will not look pretty. You will want to find something to fix that.

It does create a baseline for the text on the bottom, but the height of the text is unpredictable for now.

```js
var para = $('.text');

var lines = [];

para.each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var text = current.text();
    var words = text.split(' ');

    current.text(words[0]);
    var height = current.height();

    var lineNr = 0;
    lines.push("");
  
    for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
        current.text(current.text() + ' ' + words[i]);

        if(current.height() == height){
          lines[lineNr] += words[i] + " ";
        }
      
        if(current.height() > height){
            height = current.height();
            
            lineNr ++;
            lines.push("");
            lines[lineNr] += words[i] + " ";
        }
    }
  
  $('.text').html("");
  
  for(var line in lines){
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    $(p).html(lines[line]);
    
    $('.text').append(p);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 40px;
}
.underlined {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.skew-text {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

p {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container underlined">
  <div class="skew-text">
    <span class="text">
      I'm a little teapot, short and stout
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I considered a solution almost identical to this, but discarded it precisely because it involved cutting up the text into separate elements. Ideally, I would like keep the text (which will be variable during runtime) in a single div, and simply align it there. If there is no way to do this, I will of course accept your answer anyway.

Comment: @csvan I've updated the answer, it might help you in your solution but does show a different issue you might need to address.